# How can i present two list in one dropdown separated by divider (first list is sugested items then divider and then default items)?

Tags: list, flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

[image: dropdown]

here is example from boorstrap 4 i would like to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ListView` like this. I included a check that if the `index` is 2, we add some nice `Divider`.

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => index == 2 ? Divider(
        color: Colors.black) : Container()),
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("$index")); // You can set Action, Another Action here
```